# Fastest way to match members of two lists

Tags: c#

I have two lists which are `orderHeaders` and `orderLines`. These are two related tables in the database however when I pull them I have to pull them separately as two different lists and then map them out to each other later. I have a solution right now but the performance is a little bit disappointing given that I have around 400k headers and 1million+ lines.

Here's my code below. Is this the standard way to iterate over and find members inside two lists or is there a more optimized approach in C#?

```
var OutboundOrderHeaders = 
     DbContext.Context.Database.SqlQuery<OutboundOrderDTO>(queryString, parameter);
var OutboundOrderHeadersList = OutboundOrderHeaders.ToList();
var OutboundOrderLine = 
     DbContext.Context.Database.SqlQuery<OutboundOrderLineDTO>(queryStringLine, parameter2);
var OutboundOrderLineList = OutboundOrderLine.ToList();

for(var i = 0; i < OutboundOrderHeadersList.Count(); i++)
{
    var LineToAdd = OutboundOrderLineList
         .Where(x => x.OutboundNumber == OutboundOrderHeadersList[i].OutboundNumber)
         .ToList() ;

    OutboundOrderHeadersList[i].OrderLine = LineToAdd;
}

return OutboundOrderHeadersList;
```

Comment: Which part is slow at the moment? You're pulling the contents from the database, which I expect will take a while with that much data, and then you're doing work in memory. You should add some diagnostics to work out what's slow. I expect it would be faster if you could do the join in the database - it's not clear *why* you believe you have to pull the complete data and then do a join in memory, rather than doing the join at the database.

Comment: The part that's slow is the for loop mapping the orderlines to their respective headers. 
I would've preferred using a join but I'm not sure how to map the result in a way that the list of orderheaders will have their list of orderlines mapped to them.

Comment: If you are getting the data from a database, consider letting the database do the work. If you index things correctly, that's something databases excel at. Otherwise, consider having your data sorted.

Comment: You'd do a group join, basically. I would pursue that rather than trying to make the next part faster. While you *can* improve the time of the in-memory part, it would be better to do it in the database to start with IMO.

Comment: I'm not suggesting changing the database itself. I'm suggesting doing a query that returns exactly the data you want back. How you do the mapping is a separate question that I'd suggest you research separately. It's really important that you're able to use the database for things it's best at - not just for this question, but in general.

Comment: The database is really simple as of the moment. Essentially there's orderHeaders with orderNumber and creation metadata. orderLine has orderLineNumber, [fk]orderNumber, and string of the item ordered. 
I know how to d a join in the database but what I don't know how to do is mapping them properly once the result is sent back to c# and that's essentially my goal to check if that'd be faster vs the mapping im doing now.
@JonSkeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in comments, I'd really try hard to do this in the database rather than in memory. But to do it in memory, `ToLookup` is probably the right way to go:

```
// Note: here I've renamed used outboundOrderLines where you've got OutboundOrderLineList,
// and orderHeaders where you've got OutboundOrderHeadersList, as simpler
// and more conventional variable names.

var linesByOutboundNumber = outboundOrderLines.ToLookup(line => line.OutboundNumber);
foreach (var orderHeader in orderHeaders)
{
    orderHeader.OrderLine = linesByOutboundNumer[orderHeader.OutboundNumber].ToList();
}
```

This builds a map going from outbound number to "all the lines with that outbound number" by going through `outboundOrderLines` *once*, rather than iterating over it for every order header.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This got the code running. I'm looking into doing this in database now using joins. Can I ask for tips on what I concept I should search for in particular? 
The result of my query is mapped properly in `headers` fields but leaves the lines to null. That was really the root of where I was confused with thus me deciding with the solution you helped me with.

Comment: @jeremiahvalero: You should look at group joins, basically. I would start by exploring it in SQL (with a colleague if you're not very familiar with SQL yourself), then work out how to map that into LINQ.